# Why crashlytics not showing exact crashed line number in swift ? It just showing the method name

Tags: ios, swift, crashlytics

Why crashlytics not showing exact crashed line number in swift ? It just showing the method name. Is there any other way to identify the exact line number. Crash happening on IBAction method.
Actually i can identified the crash by seeing the force unwrapped code but not able to reproduce the scenario manually.

App written in **Objective C and swift**

Crashlytics version - 3.4.0

Crash Logs follows :

```
    #0. Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  AppName                 0x100d246c4 specialized CrashingViewController.ButtonClicked(sender : UIButton) -> () + 4342810308
1  AppName                0x1008c7208 @objc CrashingViewController.ButtonClicked(sender : UIButton) -> () + 4338233864
2  AppName                 0x1006192f8 @objc CrashingViewController.ButtonClicked(sender : UIButton) -> () + 4335424248
3  UIKit                          0x18bb5c20c -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 96
4  UIKit                          0x18bb5c18c -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 80
5  UIKit                          0x18bb46f4c -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 440
6  UIKit                          0x18bb5ba80 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 576
7  UIKit                          0x18bb5b5a0 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2544
8  UIKit                          0x18bb56a70 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 3208
9  UIKit                          0x18bb28078 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 340
10 AppName                 0x1009c18d4 -[BCApplication sendEvent:] + 4339259604
11 UIKit                          0x18c467f98 __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 2364
12 UIKit                          0x18c46a408 __handleEventQueueInternal + 4760
13 UIKit                          0x18c463574 __handleHIDEventFetcherDrain + 152
14 CoreFoundation                 0x1826c0358 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
15 CoreFoundation                 0x1826c02d8 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 88
16 CoreFoundation                 0x1826bfb60 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 204
17 CoreFoundation                 0x1826bd738 __CFRunLoopRun + 1048
18 CoreFoundation                 0x1825de2d8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
19 GraphicsServices               0x18446ff84 GSEventRunModal + 100
20 UIKit                          0x18bb8b880 UIApplicationMain + 208
21 AppName                 0x100d64f10 main (main.m:6)
22 libdyld.dylib                  0x18210256c start + 4
```

Comment: have you added bit code while archiving your build?

Comment: @AnuragSoni No . EnableBitCode is No on Buildsetting Build Option

Comment: @karthikPrabhu -   you are not get any information like `TableViewController.m line 159` in crashlytics or in your Mail

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik No. I updated the question with logs. please check

Comment: @karthikPrabhu - ya its looks different, but in my side its shows correctly

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Your App is completely written by swift only or Objective C only  or mixed with Objective C and Swift. My App is written in Objective C and swift

Comment: @karthikPrabhu - combined with both

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Are you able to get the exact line number of crash happened in IBAction ?

Comment: Thanks. Do you have dwarf w/dSYM set for all build types in Xcode debug information format?

Comment: Yes @ToddBurner

Comment: I resolved this issue by adding the following command to a new "Run Script Build Phase": `"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/upload-symbols" -gsp "${PROJECT_DIR}/GoogleService-Info.plist" -p ios "${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}"`